# Proof of Rivlin–Ericksen representation theorem relies on arbitrary tensors

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory, continuum-mechanics

I am having philosophical difficulties with the use of arbitrary orthogonal tensors in the proof of the [Rivlin–Ericksen representation theorem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=rivlin+ericksen+representation+theorem) on page 6 of the these [lecture notes](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/112103167/module1/lec12.pdf#page=6) (author unknown; from the Continuum Mechanics module at National Programme on Technology Enhanced Learning India/IIT Guwahati. I am not enrolled in either institution. I merely use the notes to supplement my self-study.)

The proof conjures proper orthogonal tensors such as ${\bf Q} = 2{\bf e}_1^\ast \otimes  {\bf e}_1^\ast - {\bf I}$ and ${\bf Q} = 2{\bf e}_2^\ast \otimes  {\bf e}_2^\ast - {\bf I}$. I am  uncomfortable with the proof of a general formula that relies on arbitrary orthogonal tensors.

BTW, similar arbitrary orthogonal tensors are also summoned in various examples 5 and 6 of the same article. Again, why is this valid?

Comment: **Trigger warning**: the given proof of “Example 1” is hideously incorrect, first off stating that the vector space might not have any vectors in it (impossible), then that for fixed $\vec u$ the function $\psi(\vec v)=\vec u\cdot\vec v$ is isotropic (it is not, shame on you), then defining a function that has no connection to the isotropic function given by assumption, but is confusingly named similar to it, then concluding quite appallingly that *all* functions are isotropic. *These class notes require an iron stomach, and sensitive/rigorous people may wish to avoid.*

Answer (score 0):

The tensors are not arbitrary. They are matrices representing  reflections in the planes perpendicular to ${\bf e}^*_i$, and, further the  ${\bf e}^*_i$ are *eigenvectors* of ${\bf S}$ ----  so the ${\bf Q}$'s are rather special objects. That being said, I do not understand the "isotopic" conditions on ${\bf G}$. I thought an isotropic tensor has to be invariant under *all* rotations and reflections, not just reflections in the principal-axis planes as these seem to be.

**Note added**:  I see by an "isotropic" function the author means what I (and most people) would call *equivariant* under rotations or reflections   i.e a rotation or reflection  of the arguments of the function lead to rotation or refection  of the output of the function.

I think he is making heavy weather of something rather  simple. Given  an isotropic material (elastic properties independent of orientation), when the strain tensor has a set of orthogonal principle axes (eigenvectors) then the stress  tensor must  have the same set of principle axes. Further, since the eigenvalues of of a three dimensional symmetric matrix obey a cubic  equation, one only to know three invariants of ${\bf S}$ to fix the arguments of any matrix function of ${\bf S}$ that has the same eigenvectors.

For example Cayley-Hamilton tells us that any real3-by-3 symmetric matrix ${\bf S}$ obeys an equation
$$
{\bf S}^3+a {\bf S}^2+b{\bf S}+c{\bf I}^3=0
$$
for some real numbers $a,b,c$. So once you know these numbers and ${\bf S}$ and ${\bf S}^2$, you can compute any power of ${\bf S}$

Comment: So if the $\bf Q$'s represent reflections in planes perpendicular to $\bf e_i^{\ast}$, in your opinion, is there any reason why can't the proof use or depend on this property instead of conjuring specific instances of $\bf Q$?